# Angular: How to control input-binding priority in ng-content?

Tags: javascript, angular

Suppouse we have this code

Parent template:

```
<wrapper>
 <custom-element [foo]="true">
</wrapper>
```

Child template (selector : 'wrapper')

```
<ng-content>
```

Child code:

```
ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.customelementRef.foo= false;
  }
```

The value of foo is false, as expected.

I want to set default value to 'false' inside ngAfterContentInit unless parent overrides it.
How can I change this code so the parent binding takes priority?

Answer (score 0):

> Use Default Value:

```
@Component(...)
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() foo: boolean = false;
}
```

> Explanation for using @Input() decorator

1. The value will remain false, unless parent changes it.
2. Whenever parent wants to change the value, all they have to do is

   `<custom-element [foo]="truthValue"> // Change the truthValue variable, and the child will take the changes.`

Comment: If I do this, then I loose the ablity to bind directly to the custom-element from parent and I this will generate a cost - I will need to teach users that they cant bind directly to custom-element. All i want is to set default values inside the custom-element from child level unless parents specifys otherwise.

Comment: @ArturStary, Input decorator is the way to go!